# Is it possible to "catch" the invalid value in MySQL when I get a foreign key constraint error?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, innodb

I'm importing a CSV file of ~150k rows into a MySQL (InnoDB) table.

At some point during the import, there's a failure because of a foreign key constraint error.

It shows which column the failure is occuring on:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`db`.`table`, CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`otherTableId`) REFERENCES `otherTable`
(`otherTableId`))
```

Is it possible to "catch" what that value is?

I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't know what to try. :P

---

Edit:

Ahh - so I found the following command in the MySQL documentation:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```

I found the following information from that command:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2014-01-22 16:27:26 2afaf98b8940 Transaction:
TRANSACTION 85952, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 944, OS thread handle 0x2afaf98b8940, query id 66223 System lock
{{QUERY}}
Foreign key constraint fails for table {TABLE INFO}:
,
  CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`Id`) REFERENCES `table` (`id`)
Trying to add in child table, in index `fk` tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
 0: len 11; hex 4163636573736f72794964; asc AccessoryId;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;

But in parent table `db`.`table`, in index `PRIMARY`,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 6; hex 46494c544552; asc FILTER;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000007300; asc     s ;;
 2: len 7; hex fb000001b01476; asc       v;;
 3: len 1; hex 46; asc F;;
 4: len 9; hex 756e646566696e6564; asc undefined;;
```

What I'm looking for in here is:

```
Trying to add in child table, in index `fk` tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
 0: len 11; hex 4163636573736f72794964; asc AccessoryId;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
```

I don't know what the 'asc' means before 'AccessoryId', but that led me to seeing that I wasn't ignoring the first line of the CSV.

---

Edit 2:

Ahh - I thought for a minute about what the 'asc' stood for, and since there's hex just before it, I assumed it meant "ASCII"

I converted the '4163636573736f72794964' into ASCII and got "AccessoryId", so that was just the HEX value of the text that I was trying to import.

---

So the answer is:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```

And search for the section titled: `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR`

You can get your info from there.  If anyone knows a better or automated way of retrieving this info, I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no better way to get the foreign key errors than from the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`. The column information is printed as e.g.:

```
Trying to add in child table, in index `fk` tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
 0: len 11; hex 4163636573736f72794964; asc AccessoryId;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
```

This is printing the full set of columns from the index (`fk`), and as you guessed the format is:

```
<column index>:
  len <length of bytes stored>;
  hex <hex representation of bytes>;
  asc <ascii representation of bytes>;;
```

Further unfortunately, InnoDB doesn't know enough about how MySQL's column types are stored to give you a reasonable printed representation, so some of the values are a bit "weird" e.g. `80000003` is the hex representation of the bytes stored for the integer 3 (InnoDB internally flips the high bit).

Comment: Thanks for the information.  At least I know, now.  :P  It was appreciated.