# How to detect the row which caused foreign key constraint violation?

Tags: mysql

For a statement such as this for the table `table1_table2_map`

```
INSERT INTO table1_table2_map 
(table1_id, table2_id) 
VALUES 
(-999,-999), -- Both Valid
(3,4), -- Both Bad
(-999, 3) -- One is Bad
```

The table mentioned above has two foreign key references:

```
 `FOREIGN KEY (`table1_id`) REFERENCES `table1_lkp` 
 ` FOREIGN KEY (`table2_id`) REFERENCES `table2_lkp`
```

The error on insert is below:

```
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test_nv2rnuw4yh`.`table1_table2_map`, CONSTRAINT `fk_table1_id` FOREIGN KEY (`table1_id`) REFERENCES `table1_lkp` (`table1_id`)).
```

How do I detect a row of information that throws the error?

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297110/is-it-possible-to-catch-the-invalid-value-in-mysql-when-i-get-a-foreign-key-co

Comment: Thanks, @Progman. Am i the only person who is puzzled as to why the error statement does not give out more details?

Answer (score 0):

If you have MySQL 8.0.19 or later you can convert you `values` into a select query like this using `row` e.g.:

```
select col1, col2
from (
    VALUES 
        row(-999,-999)
     ,  row(3,4),
     ,  row(-999, 3)  
      ) d (col1, col2)
where not exists (select null from table1_lkp where d.col1 = table1_lkp.table1_id)
or not exists (select null from table2_lkp where d.col2 = table2_lkp.table2_id)
```

If you cannot use `row` then convert the values in a query that uses union all to form the needed rows

```
select col1, col2
from (
    select -999 as col1 ,-999 as col2 union all
    select 3,4 union all
    select -999, 3 union all 
      ) d
where not exists (select null from table1_lkp where d.col1 = table1_lkp.table1_id)
or not exists (select null from table2_lkp where d.col2 = table2_lkp.table2_id)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i am using Mysql 5.6. does that matter? i'll try your suggestion and post back

Comment: for old versions of MySQL you will need to use the second method because `row` was introduced with MySQL 8.0.19  see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html